# Using Unions of enums in C

Tags: c, enums, unions

I am using pointers to functions in state machines and need to pass an enumerated value that is built from a a union of enums.  As I am using a table with functions calls I need their call/return values to match.  I have tried to build this on my local box and on CodeChef using GCC C 4.9.2  With codeChef I'm getting the error:

> prog.c: In function 'main': prog.c:12:15: error: expected expression
>   before 'FOO'    NewFooState(FOO.D);       // <<<<<< This is what
>   fails!!

```
typedef enum Foo_t {A, B, C, D} FOO;
typedef enum Bar_t {E, F, G} BAR;


typedef union FooBar_t {FOO Foo; BAR Bar;} FooBar;

FooBar NewFooState(FooBar NewState);

//I want to later make call such as

int main(){
  NewFooState(FOO.D);       // <<<<<< This is what fails!!
  return 0;
}
//and have that function look like:

FooBar NewFooState(FooBar NewState){
  static FooBar oldState = {.Foo=A};
  FooBar ReturnValue = oldState;
  oldState = NewState;
  switch (NewState.Foo){
      case A:
      case B:
      case C:
      case D:
        //stuff
        break;
  }
  return ReturnValue ;
}
```

Note the particular way that is needed to initialize oldState:

> static FooBar oldState = {.Foo=A};

My problem seems to be using enum value such as **FooBar.Bar.G** I've tried all of the syntax combinations that see obvious to me such as {.Foo=G}, FooBar_t.Bar.G, Bar.G, G, etc but I can not get the compiler to accept it.  I just want to use one of the enumerated values such as F and call the NewFooState function, such as NewFooState(F).  Should be so simple...
With NewFooState(G) I am getting the error Error[Pe167]: argument of type "enum G" is incompatible with parameter of type "FooBar"

Comment: G is not a field, it is its own identifier.

Comment: What compiler error does `NewFooState(G)` give you?

Comment: jxh, Oddly enough switching on NewState does seem to compile and work just fine.

Comment: Please update your question to show us your actual code. Your union type has a member of type `Foo_t`. There's a type `Foo`, and a type `enum Foo_t`, but no type `Foo_T` (unless you're  compiling the code as C++, in which case you need to update the tag). And there's a missing semicolon on `OldState = NewState`. Given errors like that, it's impossible to tell what the actual problem is. See [mcve].

Comment: There are no namespaces in C. So there is no such thing as `FOO.D` or `Foo_t.D`. All you done is define `A=0`, `B=1`, `C=2` and `D=3`. And `E=0`, `F=1` and `G=2`. Making a union that contains `FOO` and `BAR` members does nothing but create trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `FOO.D`. `D` is its own identifier which designates an enum value associated with `FOO`. However, your `NewFooState()` function expects a `FooBar`, not `FOO` (nor `BAR`). So, you need a variable of the proper type. One way this can be done:

```
  FooBar FOO_D = { .Foo=D };
  NewFooState(FOO_D);
```